# does php mysql_fetch_array works with html input box?

Tags: php, mysql, html-input

this is my entire PHP code:

```
<?php if(empty($_POST['selid']))
        {echo "no value selected";  }
        else 
        {
            $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            if(mysql_select_db("cdcol", $con))
                {
                    $sql= "SELECT * FROM products where Id = '$_POST[selid]'";

                    if($result=mysql_query($sql))
                    {   

                        echo "<form name=\"updaterow\" method=\"post\" action=\"dbtest.php\">";
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                        { 
                        echo "Id :<input type=\"text\" name=\"ppId\" value=".$row['Id']." READONLY></input></br>";
                        echo "Name :<input type=\"text\" name=\"pName\" value=".$row['Name']."></input></br>";
                        echo "Description :<input type=\"text\" name=\"pDesc\" value=".$row['Description']."></input></br>";
                        echo "Unit Price :<input type=\"text\" name=\"pUP\" value=".$row['UnitPrice']."></input></br>";
                        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"mode\" value=\"Update\"/>";

                        }
                        echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\">";
                        echo "</form>";
                    }
                    else {echo "Query ERROR";}
                }
        }
?>
```

**PROBLEM** here is, ....if the value i am getting from database using `mysql_fetch_array($result)`  is like:(say Description is:) "my product"

then;
in input box it shows only  **"my"** the word(or digit)
 after "SPACE"(ie blank space) doesn't get displayed?
can input box like above can display the data with two or more words(separated by blank spaces)?

Comment: use mysqli instead of mysql_connect. And templating system like FastTemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "Unit Price :<input type=\"text\" name=\"pUP\" value=\"".$row['UnitPrice']."\"></input></br>";
```

You need to enclose `value` in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The html parser has no way of knowing that <input value=abc def...> means value=`abc def`. It has to parse it as two attributes, the attribute `value` with the value `abc` and the attribute `def` without a value.

You have to enclose the value in quotes, e.g. <input value="abc def" ...>
You also have to encode " as &quot; within the value. Otherwise the html parser will get confused again, since it has no way of knowing that the second " in value="abc"def" is not a delimeter but part of the content. You can use [htmspecialchars()](http://docs.php.net/htmspecialchars) for this.

e.g.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  printf('
    Id :<input type="text" name="ppId" value="%s" READONLY></input><br>
    Name :<input type="text" name="pName" value="%s"></input><br>
    Description :<input type="text" name="pDesc" value="%s"></input><br>
    Unit Price :<input type="text" name="pUP" value="%s"></input><br>";
    <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="Update"/>',
    htmlspecialchars($row['Id']),
    htmlspecialchars($row['Name']),
    htmlspecialchars($row['Description']),
    htmlspecialchars($row['UnitPrice'])
  );
}
```